# how to save capture the video in local file

Tags: iphone, file, video

I want capture the video using iPhone application. In this video file i want store the local application. how to save this file in locally. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{      
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];

    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];


    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```